# Getting average of two or more values in OpenRefine

Tags: openrefine, grel

I have imported a csv file into the OpenRefine that includes a column for string text values as "Name" and another column that contains corresponding numerical values for those text values. I want to get the average of those numerical values when I merge two or more Name values.

I went to "add column based on column..." and tried several codes in "General Refine Expression Language (GREL)" in that expression box but it did not work or returned empty cells. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Can you go into more detail what you mean by "merging two or more Name values"?